# Supremum and norm property.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I am just wondering why the following equalities are true:

$$\begin{aligned} \sup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \left\{ \langle u, x \rangle - \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 \right\} &= \sup\limits_{t \geq0, \|x\| = t} \{ \langle u,x \rangle - \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 \}\\ &= \sup\limits_{t \geq0} \{t \cdot\sup\limits_{\|x\| = 1} \langle u, x \rangle - \frac{1}{2} \|x\|^2 \} \\ &= \sup\limits_{t \geq0} \{t \|u\| - \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 \}\end{aligned}$$

I have some intuition about them, but I don't get clearly how to prove it analytically.

Comment: In the second term, where is the $t$?

Comment: @TaoX Anywhere, that's why I'm asking for them to be true.

Comment: Consider  Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Is there a $\sup$ over $x$ in the last expression?

Comment: @gerw No. It's not.

Comment: Then, it does not make sense. The last expression depends on $x$ whereas the other expressions do not depend on $x$ (due to the sup).

Comment: @Lecter This seems incorrect. The LHS is supposed to give you $(1/2)\|u\|^2$ by Cauchy--Schwarz inequality, whereas the last one gives you $+\infty$ if $u\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}
\Big(
\left\langle
u,x
\right\rangle
-\dfrac{1}{2}\|x\|^2
\Big)
&=
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}
\Big(
\frac{1}{2}\|u\|^2+
\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2-
\frac{1}{2}\|u-x\|^2
-\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2
\Big)
\\
&=
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}
\Big(
\frac{1}{2}\|u\|^2-
\frac{1}{2}\|x-u\|^2
\Big)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\|u\|^2.
\end{align}
$$
However,
since $\lim_{t\to+\infty}t\|u\|=+\infty$ if $u\neq 0$,
the last expression in your question gives $+\infty$
when $u\neq 0$, showing that the equality in your question is...incorrect.